# C signal handler getting activated by all child processes

Tags: c, process, signals

I need some kind of signal_handler that when pressed CTRL+C, the program pauses all it's operations and asks the user: «Are you sure you want to terminate(Y/N)?» If the answer is y, the program terminates, if it's n the program continues/prooceeds with it's functions, this is what i have till this moment:

```
void sig_handler(int sig){
    if(sig == SIGINT){

        char res;
        printf("\nAre you sure you want to terminate (Y/N)?\n");
        kill(0, SIGTSTP); //envia sinal Stop ao processo pai

        do{
            read(STDIN_FILENO, &res, 1);
            if (res == 'Y' || res == 'y')
            {
                kill(0,SIGTERM); //envia sinal de Terminacao ao proceso pai
            }else
                if (res == 'N' || res == 'n')
                {
                    kill(0,SIGCONT); //envia sinal ao processo pai para continuar
                    break;
                }
        }while(res != 'Y' && res != 'y' && res != 'N' && res != 'n');
    }

}

struct sigaction oldsigaction; //declarar antes de subscribe_SIGINT

void subscribe_SIGINT(){
    sigaction(SIGTSTP, 0,&oldsigaction);
    struct sigaction newsigaction;
    newsigaction = oldsigaction;
    newsigaction.sa_handler = &sig_handler;
    sigaction(SIGTSTP, &newsigaction,0);
    signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);
}
```

The problem with this code is that the message «Are you sure you want to terminate(Y/N)?» appears more then once, i suppose that happens because all the child processes of the program activate this signal_handler when CTRL+C is pressed.
Any solutions?

Comment: Create the signal handler in the parent process after you fork all the children. Or revert the signal handler in the children to default.

Comment: `printf()` is not async-signal-safe.  You are not permitted to call it from a signal handler.  You can call `read()` and `write()`, but be careful of the possibility of interfering with stream operations on the same open file description.

Comment: Or the signal handler could check a global variable to determine if it's the original parent or a child.

Comment: This isn't the problem you're asking about, but `kill(0, SIGTSTP)` is wrong - it will prevent you from reacting to input.

Comment: Assuming you are using Unix/Linux, I suggest you read "man 7 signal" for a list of "async-safe functions" that may be called in a signal handler (you will notice 'printf()' is not among them'.

Comment: Here's a nice discussion of signal handling when you have child processes, and are using CNTL-C:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176235/fork-and-how-signals-are-delivered-to-processes

Comment: Given that all the processes in the process group will receive the signal from the controlling terminal of the process group, you have limited options.  One option is to have just one process go interactive on interrupt; all the others either ignore interrupts or die on interrupts.  Another is to isolate some of the processes from the process group and controlling terminal.  If they must all go interactive, you face a nightmare.  They'll all prompt, but you won't be able to tell beforehand which process gets which input.  Thus if you wanted to stop some and let others continue, you're stuck.