# C Linux Signal Handler for the Main Process Only

Tags: c, linux, process, signals, handler

I am making a program that creates numerous processes using `fork()`, which then calls an `exec` function to the same program (this is required by the professor).

I need it to react to CTRL+C (SIGINT) and ask the user if he/she wants to leave. The problem is that the signal handler is implemented in all the child processes too, so, when the signal is sent, the user has to answer the same amount of times as the number of processes.

I only want it to ask the user once per CTRL+C.

What solutions can I implement?

Comment: Fork first, set up signal-handling later? Or in the children, before `exec`, set the signal-handler to default?

Comment: The process generated by fork() will fork() too, so either way it will install the handler in (almost) all processes.

Comment: The first set of child processes will know they are child processes, and so will continue down a different path than the first "main" process. If they don't I would say your design seems flawed.

Comment: Your classmate [asked about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43379322/c-signal-handler-getting-activated-by-all-child-processes) yesterday.  And he provided code.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `fork()`, the parent process will get back the pid of the child. You can send a SIGTERM or SIGKILL signal to the children through the `kill` syscall when the parent receives the SIGINT signal.

Comment: The problem is not how to send signals to the children; it is that the children are *already receiving* the `SIGINT`, and handling it differently than the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a global variable pid and populate it with the result of getpid() on launch. And inside the signal handler test getpid() against pid then execute your code. Something like, if you are the main process please proceed, if not exit!

End result: You will have a signal handler that is run once by the main process....